# How to style a Mermaid subgraph's title?

Tags: mermaid

How to style the title in a Mermaid subgraph?  I would like to make the font larger and add some blank space between the title and the first node beneath it.

I tried adding some `<br/>'s` after the title but that pushed the title above the boundary of the subgraph.

```
graph TB

subgraph someID[Some Title]
    direction TB
    ....
end
```

Answer (score 12):

Styling a subgraph title seem to work like this:

```
graph TB
subgraph ED[Every Day]
   A <--> B
end

style ED color:#f66
```

Caveat: I'm using Microsoft Github's in-browser Mermaid markdown preview and I'm not sure to what degree their implementation is conformant.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for styling that do not include coloring, you may try something like this:

```
someID:::someClass

subgraph someID[Some Title]
    someItem(The subgraph title has some style)
end 

classdef someClass padding-left:5em;
```

Reference: [Mermaid classes](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/flowchart?id=classes)

Answer (score 3):

You can add bold, italics, etc. via Markdown if you put the text in tics and double quotes (tics inside). **Example**:

```
graph TB
    subgraph ABC["`part of heading in **bold**`"]
        A --> B
        C --> D
    end
```

**Output**:

[image: Mermaid.js output]

**Documentation**: https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/flowchart.html#markdown-formatting

(This feature requires [Mermaid 10.1](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/releases/tag/v10.1.0) or newer. [As of 2023-11-26](https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material/releases/tag/9.4.13), [Material for MkDocs](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/changelog/) includes Mermaid 10.6.1.)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no possibility to style the title at the moment (see this [pull request](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/pull/845)).

> Note that given how subgraph SVG tags are built up, there is no (current) way to style the title text.

Comment: the markdown type styling (bold, italics) is available, better than nothing
https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/flowchart.html#markdown-formatting

Answer (score 0):

I use an additional 'blank' subgraph using styles (classDef) to add space for larger fonts in the parent subgraph.

```
subgraph main[mainTitle]

    %% single space in [ ] to not display text
    subgraph padding[ ]

        subgraph child[childTitle]

            %% child nodes

        end

    end

    %% main nodes

end

classDef title font-size:14px
classDef padding stroke:none,fill:none

class main title
class padding padding
```

Comment: This somehow breaks the mermaid.live editor